# How do I match for a specific URL with a RewriteCond

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I get this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://www\.example\.com/example/thing\+1234/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^503\.html - [F]
```

To match this url:

```
https://www.example.com/example/thing+1234/
```

I've tried various online regex tools which DO make the above match. I tried escaping the forward slashes, tried it with and without escaping the plus sign, but my server won't match it. All I want to do is kill traffic coming from an unwanted source. It must be something simple but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

With the line

`RewriteRule ^503\.html - [F]`

you define that the rule applies only for requests which match the pattern `^503\.html`.

I think you wantend to use

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]`

instead, which blocks all requests. For the flags have a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html).

Comment: Ah, got it - now where did I even get that part from? Funny how you don't think to look at the obvious. Thanks.